# carriage return in sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Hey I am using the following query to display the problem list separated by commas.

```
SELECT tt.VrNo, STUFF((select ','+ Er1.ErrorDesc 
from ( select * from CallRegErrors )as Main 
left join ErrorMaster ER1 on Main.ErrorCode=ER1.ErrorCode
WHERE (main.VrNo = tt.VrNo)
FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,'') AS Problemlist
```

query is giving the output like a,b,c,d etc

But my actual requirement is I want to display each error description in a new line like,
a
b
c
d
etc

I tried the following query for it:

```
SELECT tt.VrNo, STUFF((select char(13)+char(10)+ Er1.ErrorDesc
from ( select * from CallRegErrors )as Main 
left join ErrorMaster ER1 on Main.ErrorCode=ER1.ErrorCode
WHERE (main.VrNo = tt.VrNo)
FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,'') AS Problemlist
```

and also i have used

SELECT tt.VrNo,Replace(STUFF((select ','+ Er1.ErrorDesc as [text()] from ( select * from CallRegErrors )as Main left join ErrorMaster ER1 on Main.ErrorCode=ER1.ErrorCode
            WHERE (main.VrNo = tt.VrNo)
            FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,''),',',char(13)+char(10)) AS Problemlist
            from (select main.VrNo, Er1.ErrorDesc from ( select * from CallRegErrors )as Main left join ErrorMaster ER1 on Main.ErrorCode=ER1.ErrorCode )as tt
            group by tt.VrNo 
but now get the problem list seperated by spaces instead of commas after using the above query

but its does not give the output that i want.

please help..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you expand on "not working"?

Comment: SSMS won't show your carriage returns...

Comment: Hmm.. if you need them in separate rows, why are you concatenating them? Why don't you just select directly?

Comment: I would try switching your query results to display as text instead of in the grid.  There is a button for this in SSMS or you can press CTRL+T.

Answer (score 3):

I think we need more information before we can help you.

I think you are trying to format the information at the child level in a parent child relationship into a list.  You probably saw something like this [blog](http://sqlandme.com/2011/04/27/tsql-concatenate-rows-using-for-xml-path/) on the web.

However, your query is not correctly formatted.

Is the ErrorMaster (Production.ProductCategory) the parent and CallRegErrors (SUB.ProductCategoryID) the child?

If so just change the query to those table name field names for it to work.

I used the REPLACE function on the overall result to change COMMAS to CR + LF.

```
-- Sample database
USE AdventureWorks2012
GO

-- Change SQL from www.sqlandme.com for this users problem
SELECT      
    CAT.Name AS [Category],
    REPLACE(STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + SUB.Name AS [text()]                        
        FROM Production.ProductSubcategory SUB
        WHERE SUB.ProductCategoryID = CAT.ProductCategoryID
        FOR XML PATH('') 
        ), 1, 1, '' ), ',', CHAR(13) + CHAR(10))
    AS [Sub Categories]
FROM  Production.ProductCategory CAT
```

You can only see carriage returns in the output window when the type is set to TEXT in SSMS.

I hope this solves your problem.  If not, please write back with more information!!

[image]